# My ubuntu18 fonts changed thin and ugly suddenly

Tags: 18.04, fonts

My font just changed thin and ugly. I tried to reset my fonts in gnome-tweaks, but it didn't work.

This is what I see:

[image]

Comment: You've probably done this, but have you restarted your machine to see if it's a cache issue?

Comment: Please be precise with details, Ubuntu releases using the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 18 like the 18 in your title) are different products to the *year.month* format (eg. 18.04 you tagged).  18 != 18.04  Have you changed font files? rebuilt cache? or done one without the other?  Telling us what you've done in before (inc. session before) this happened is likely key.